# Insert UUID with RDSDataservice

Tags: typescript, postgresql, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I want to insert with the RDS Dataservice a UUID native type, but I get a conversion error.

```
const statement = `INSERT INTO entity (
                                id
                   )
                   VALUES (
                                :id
                   )`;

        const params: RDSDataService.Types.ExecuteStatementRequest = {
            parameters: [
                {name: 'id', value: {stringValue: entity.id}},
            ],
            sql: statement,
            ...this.databaseParameters
        };

        return this.data.executeStatement(params).promise()
```

With the following schema:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE entity
(
    id                  uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I get the following:

```
ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression
```

It does work if I interpolate the id:

```
const statement = `INSERT INTO entity (
                                id
                   )
                   VALUES (
                                '${entity.id}'
                   )`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by explicitly casting every value that I insert:

```
const statement = `INSERT INTO entity (
                                id
                   )
                   VALUES (
                                CAST(:id AS uuid)
                   )`;
```